# T-SQL query to get the following results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question which I faced in an interview.

Can you please provide the solution for this?

[image]

Comment: That's a hell of an interview.

Comment: Ezlo...I completely agree with you. If they want to reject a candidate they will ask this type of question. But as a t-sql developer i should know the solution so i am seeking you guys help.

Comment: You should know thew solution. If you don't know the solution you should _try_ to find a solution. What have you tried?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt this by [UNPIVOTing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) the data and use [ROW_Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the integer for the ColumnName like so

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( Column1 CHAR(1), Column2 CHAR(3))
INSERT INTO @t
(Column1,Column2)
VALUES
('A', 'AAA') ,('B', 'BBB') ,('C', 'CCC') ,('D', 'DDD') 

SELECT 
     ColData = T.Column1
    ,ColName = 'Column1.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS NVARCHAR(5))
FROM @t T
UNION
SELECT 
     ColData = T.Column2
    ,ColName = 'Column2.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS NVARCHAR(5))
FROM @t T
```

which gives this result

```
ColData ColName
A       Column1.1
AAA     Column2.1
B       Column1.2
BBB     Column2.2
C       Column1.3
CCC     Column2.3
D       Column1.4
DDD     Column2.4
```

So then wrap this in a PIVOT query to get required output

```
SELECT
    [Column1.1],[Column2.1],[Column1.2],[Column2.2],[Column1.3],[Column2.3],[Column1.4],[Column2.4]
FROM(
        SELECT 
             ColData = T.Column1
            ,ColName = 'Column1.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS NVARCHAR(5))
        FROM @t T
        UNION
        SELECT 
             ColData = T.Column2
            ,ColName = 'Column2.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS NVARCHAR(5))
        FROM @t T
)AS Tab
PIVOT 
(  
    MAX(ColData)  
    FOR ColName IN ([Column1.1],[Column2.1],[Column1.2],[Column2.2],[Column1.3],[Column2.3],[Column1.4],[Column2.4])  
) AS PIV;
```

Output

```
Column1.1   Column2.1   Column1.2   Column2.2   Column1.3   Column2.3   Column1.4   Column2.4
A            AAA         B           BBB         C           CCC         D           DDD
```

Comment: This may work... But your approach using `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)` leads to a random result actually. This can work a thousand times and suddenly return a result in a different order...

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Its working at my End.

```
   SELECT
    [Column1.1],[Column2.1],[Column1.2],[Column2.2],[Column1.3],[Column2.3],[Column1.4],[Column2.4]
FROM(
        SELECT 
             ColData = Table1.Column1
            ,ColName = 'Column1.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS NVARCHAR(5))
        FROM Table1
        UNION
        SELECT 
             ColData = Table1.Column2
            ,ColName = 'Column2.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS NVARCHAR(5))
        FROM  Table1
)AS Tab
PIVOT 
(  
    MAX(ColData)  
    FOR ColName IN ([Column1.1],[Column2.1],[Column1.2],[Column2.2],[Column1.3],[Column2.3],[Column1.4],[Column2.4])  
) AS PIV;
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: This may work... But your approach using `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)` leads to a random result actually. This can work a thousand times and suddenly return a result in a different order...

Answer (score 0):

`PIVOT` with more than one column can be done with *conditional aggregation*:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( c1 CHAR(1), c2 CHAR(3))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
 ('A', 'AAA') 
,('B', 'BBB') 
,('C', 'CCC') 
,('D', 'DDD');

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1) AS RowIndex 
    FROM @t
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RowIndex=1 THEN c1 END) AS [Column1.1]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowIndex=1 THEN c2 END) AS [Column2.1]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowIndex=2 THEN c1 END) AS [Column1.2]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowIndex=2 THEN c2 END) AS [Column2.2]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowIndex=3 THEN c1 END) AS [Column1.3]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowIndex=3 THEN c2 END) AS [Column2.3]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowIndex=4 THEN c1 END) AS [Column1.4]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowIndex=4 THEN c2 END) AS [Column2.4]
FROM Numbered
```